# I need to find an xmpp java server that is opensource and supports video-conferencing

Tags: open-source, xmpp, smack, video-conferencing

I am trying to implement a client side software (a messenger) in java that uses XMPP and supports videoconferencing. For this goal I've downloaded smack and tried to work with it, so I need an xmpp java server that is open source and supports videoconferencing. Then I could connect my database to this server and use it.
Is there any server as I need?

Comment: So, you asked Google (because that is what you do when you are looking for something) and it came up empty, and now you are asking here because Google is probably wrong? Or what exactly have you been thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [XMPP with MultiMedia Jingle](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/). But the Jingle implementation in smack is pretty old, you have to find out if it works for you. Also I think that Jingle currently only supports one-to-one video-chat, there is a multiparty Jingle [XEP but it's deferred](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0272.html). The good news is that it's relatively server independent, all logic and negotiation is done on the client side. 
If you are looking for a Java XMPP Server, give [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) a try. Openfire is also open-source. But you don't need an Java XMPP Server just because Smack is written in java. There are [many alternatives](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/).

You are basically asking for some *sophisticated* solution for free/as open-source. But AFAIK no one has taken the effort to built something like that (yet). If you have the manpower, time and knowledge, you are sure welcome to contribute to the community. :)

Comment: thanks Flow for your very helpful answer,I did some research about open fire and as I realized it needs a plugin named red5.war for supporting video-chat,now i dont know it supports jingle and multiparty jingle or not?and also about smack,does it support multiparty jingle or not? also i did not realized what you mean about server independant? thank for your helps,I m very new in xmpp and smack and i need so many help to do what i want.